# Using VirtualEnv with Python3.5 in Windows, FileNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm trying to start using virtualenv, but I keep running into the error below:
I installed virtualenv with pip8.1.2

```
C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\first_django_app>virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\jeff\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jeff\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\jeff\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jeff\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 711, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "c:\users\jeff\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 924, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "c:\users\jeff\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1136, in install_python
    copy_tcltk(prefix, home_dir, symlink)
  File "c:\users\jeff\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1077, in copy_tcltk
    copyfileordir(srcdir, dstdir, symlink)
  File "c:\users\jeff\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 329, in copyfileordir
    shutil.copy2(src, dest)
  File "c:\users\jeff\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 251, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "c:\users\jeff\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\jeff\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32/tcl/tcl8.6'
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by just creating directories where the program expected them to be. So under the Python35-32 folder, I added a tcl folder containing tcl8.6 and tk8.6 folders.

Comment: For the record: This was a bug in virtualenv, https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/929, fixed in https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/937, a couple of months after this question was asked.  In an environment where I still have an older virtualenv, this works fine for me.